# How can I remove all rows of a dataframe that have the same string value across a subset of columns in R?

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

| ID | Time | Q1 | Q2 | Q3 | Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 min | Agree | NA | Neutral | NA |
| 2 | 5 min | NA | Disagree | Agree | NA |
| 3 | 3 min | Agree | NA | Neutral | NA |
| 4 | 5 min | Disagree | Disagree | NA | NA |
| 5 | 6 min | NA | Agree | Agree | Agree |
| 6 | 1 min | NA | NA | NA | NA |

I want to retain only the rows for which responses to the questions are not equivalent across Question columns (Q1:Q4). In this example, I would retain rows for IDs 1-3 and remove rows 4-6, as they are all identical strings. I do want to keep the information from the first two columns, but I don't want to use it in the decision logic regarding whether or not to keep the row. All rows have NAs, but the NAs are in various places - so I want to remove rows for which all columns that have any value in them are the same, or rows for which all values across columns are missing.

I found another answer that did something similar and tried this:

```
keep <- apply(df[3:6], 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) != 1)
df[keep, ]
```

but that seemed to only remove rows that were all NAs.

Comment: Could you clarify - you say you want to keep rows 1-3 because  "responses to the questions are equivalent across Question columns (Q1:Q4)" - but they are not equivalent in rows 1-3. Conversely, you want to remove rows 4-6, but they _are_ equivalent (except 6 which has `NA`s).

Comment: Yes, thank you - I modified. I want to remove all rows for which values are equivalent across columns

Answer (score 1):

To keep all those with discordant responses (assumed ignoring `NA`s), you can try this slight change in your attempted code:

```
keeps <- apply(df[3:6], 1, function(x) !length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) %in% 0:1)
df[keeps, ]

#    ID Time    Q1       Q2      Q3   Q4
# 1  1 2min Agree     <NA> Neutral <NA>
# 2  2 5min  <NA> Disagree   Agree <NA>
# 3  3 3min Agree     <NA> Neutral <NA>
```

If you want all those with identical responses (assumed ignoring `NA`s):

```
keeps <- apply(df[3:6], 1, function(x) length(unique(x[!is.na(x)])) == 1)
df[keeps, ]

#    ID Time       Q1       Q2    Q3    Q4
# 4  4 5min Disagree Disagree  <NA>  <NA>
# 5  5 6min     <NA>    Agree Agree Agree
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID Time    Q1  Q2  Q3  Q4
1   2min    Agree   NA  Neutral NA
2   5min    NA  Disagree    Agree   NA
3   3min    Agree   NA  Neutral NA
4   5min    Disagree    Disagree    NA  NA
5   6min    NA  Agree   Agree   Agree
6   1min    NA  NA  NA  NA", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried doing this, and it only removes rows that have all NAs for some reason. It may be relevant that it's using length, and the number of characters in each string value differs (e.g., "Neutral" is 6 letters, but "Agree" is 5, and "Disagree" is 8). I"m not sure if that is even what the problem is, though. I get the feeling my initial solution was not even close.

Comment: @EmpiricalOstrich Thats odd, it's working on my sample data. Could you edit your question to provide a sample of your exact data structute using `dput`? The `length` shouldn't have anything to do with the number of characters in a string, but rather the number of unique strings in the vector

Comment: So I looked more in depth here, and it looks like there was an issue with my data - other variables within the range of the columns that had random values (e.g., open-ended input). When I removed those columns, zephryl's solution worked - and the reason I went with theirs was because I understood it a bit better. Thank you so much for your help!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dplyr-based solution: group using `rowwise()`, then filter to rows with > 1 distinct value across columns.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(n_distinct(c_across(Q1:Q4), na.rm = TRUE) > 1) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 3 × 6
     ID Time  Q1    Q2       Q3      Q4   
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>   <chr>
1     1 2min  Agree NA       Neutral NA   
2     2 5min  NA    Disagree Agree   NA   
3     3 3min  Agree NA       Neutral NA
```

Comment: This worked! It turns out that the problem was using 1 as the filter - I think maybe R was counting NA as a distinct value, so when I used this code exactly, it only removed rows with all NAs - but when I changed the 1 to a 2, it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```r
data <- data.frame(ID = 1:6, Time = c("2 min", "5 min", "3 min", 
"5 min", "6 min", "1 min"), Q1 = c("Agree", NA, "Agree", "Disagree", 
NA, NA), Q2 = c(NA, "Disagree", NA, "Disagree", "Agree", NA), 
    Q3 = c("Neutral", "Agree", "Neutral", NA, "Agree", NA), Q4 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Agree", NA))

rows <- apply(data[3:6], 1, \(x) all(x[!is.na(x)][1] == x[!is.na(x)][-1]) )

data[!rows,]
#>   ID  Time    Q1       Q2      Q3   Q4
#> 1  1 2 min Agree     <NA> Neutral <NA>
#> 2  2 5 min  <NA> Disagree   Agree <NA>
#> 3  3 3 min Agree     <NA> Neutral <NA>
```